# Setting CLion remote toolchains through SSH tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, clion, jetbrains-ide, tunneling

Currently, I am developing a C application on a server for developing with vim.
In order to connect the server, first I have to connect a gateway server with Yubikey authentication and then I can connect to the server for developing with Kerberos authentication from the gateway server.

I want set remote toolchains on my CLion IDE to the server.

How can I do that in this situation?